# Powershell - Manually trigger a scheduled job

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have created a powershell job that I can see when I use the following command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ScheduledJob -Name KillTicker | Get-JobTrigger

Id         Frequency       Time                   DaysOfWeek              Enabled
--         ---------       ----                   ----------              -------
1          AtStartup                                                      True
```

As this is a startup job I really don't fancy restarting to test it out - ***how to do I manually start this job?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run `Get-ScheduledJob -id 1 | Get-Member` to retrieve all Members of a `Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobDefinition` you will see that the object expose a method called `StartJob`:

```
(Get-ScheduledJob -id 1).StartJob()
```

To retrieve the result, use the [Receive-Job](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113372) cmdlet:

```
Receive-Job -id 1
```

Comment: Perfect - I was unaware of `Get-Member` to discover methods

Comment: Well, `Get-Member` alias `gm` is one of my most used cmdlet - and I think yours soon too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is worth it to mention that Start-Job or StartJob() both run the defined job from the current security context. If the job runs as different user or accesses network resources, you might get unexpected results.

To get the same behavior use either `(Get-ScheduledJob -Name xxx).RunAsTask()` or `Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName xxx -TaskPath xxx`. The latter provides a `-CimSession` option and could be better for remote operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Start-Job` cmdlet and supply the name of the Scheduled Job as the 
`-DefinitionName` parameter.

```
Start-Job -DefinitionName *MyJobName*
```